# How to send a Notification to a specific user, using ChannelUri on a .net backend

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have earlier used windows phone 8.0 with javascript backend, which enabled me to send pushnotifications to specific user based on the stored ChannelUri in my tables.

I have since then moved on to .net since I can then use class' on my client and on the server for verification. However I am not able to find a way of sending to specific users. I am not using NotificationHub, and I am only planning on doing this at later point for broadcasting but for normal communication to other users I would like to send Notifications directed at a user.

I have found [this link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-push-notifications-app-users/), that users tags to send to specific users(my users are authenticated). I however would like to know if this is the only solution or if you could also use channelUri and if so how you do it?

Basicly how to send a pudhnotification from server side directed at a specific user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a scenario earlier. My server needs to push content to the connected clients in real time. For this I had used [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).
If my understanding is correct, this should suit your situation too.

Comment: That might Work. I was just hoping that I could just use the channeluri I get on the client side. So I would upload that and write to that channel to write directly to the use also when they were not online :)

Comment: We are using signal R to push data to multiple clients, and its instant. It uses a fallback mechanism for browser backward compatibility, Clients register with the server creating a forever frame and data is pushed to and from in this 'always open' connection, very nifty. and very quick.